# Как добавить jre в exe файл в launch4j

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

Есть программа в формате `jar`, надо упаковать ее в `exe` файл. Все упаковывается, но на другом компьютере вылетает ошибка, что нет установленной `java`.

Comment: Везде искал, но понятного ответа так и не нашлось

Comment: Вроде как в Intellij IDEA такое можно сделать. Он кидает кучу дополнительных файлов к exe-шнику.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо использовать следующую конфигурацию для упаковки JRE в выполняемый файл

```
<jre>
    <path>путь/jre</path> 
</jre>
```