# Можно ли сделать исполняемый файл приложения, написанного на java с расширением не jar, а exe?

Tags: java, javafx, gui, jar, exe

Я создал приложение на языке java, но проблема в том, что после создания исполняемого jar файла, я могу его запустить только со специальным программным обеспечением, соответственно если кто-то попытается его запустить с другого компьютера, у него ничего не выйдет.
Как сделать исполняемый файл с расширением exe?

Comment: Да, конечно. Вот некоторые ресурсы: [1](https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html),
[2](https://www.programcreek.com/2009/05/convert-java-jar-file-to-exe/),
Так же подобный вопрос уже был задан на стек оверфлоу: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272107/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-file-to-an-exe-file)

Comment: Можно использовать lanch4j и [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/860358/204920) ответ.

Comment: А как сделать это в intelij IDEA?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли как сделать, чтобы jar файл запускался на компьютерах без установленного JRE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/911049/204271)

Comment: Не дубликат, так как в том вопросе не идёт речи об exe

Comment: @НиколайСеменов там во всех трёх ответах есть про способ сделать exe'шник. Кроме того, вам нужен именно exe'шник или надо просто чтобы программа запускалась на других компьютерах?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, главное чтобы запускалась без установки на них java

Comment: @НиколайСеменов тогда jlink - лучший вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы преобразовать jar в exe, нужно скачать Launch4j, установить путь к начальному файлу и конечному результату (с нужным расширением)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажать на вкладку JRE, в пункте Min JRE version написать 1.6.0_22
После чего нажать на шестерёнку, вбить имя доп файла и нажать save

Comment: Отлично преобразует, но есть одна проблема, когда я переношу созданный файл на другой компьютер, он перестаёт работать и предлагает скачать java

Comment: Это всего лишь Загрузчик приложения на java, то есть java всё равно необходимо установить. Если вы хотите обычное exe то только переписывать вручную.

Comment: @coder675, но как его вручную переписать?

Comment: Берете исходный код. Если файл не ваш, то используете Java Decompiler. Используя навык понимания чужого java кода, пишите программу на каком то похожем языке. Я к сожалению java знаю лишь поверхностно. Для того чтобы это проделать нужен определенный опыт в программировании. Если его нет либо учитесь, либо наймите программиста который сможет переписать код.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы используете IntelliJ тогда в **Project Structure** -> **Artifacts**  -> выберите Native Bundle: **All**

[image]

далее выберите во вкладке Build -> Build Artifact -> имя приложения -> Build

---

*.exe файл вы найдете тут:

> USER\IdeaProjects\projectname\out\artifacts\projectname\bundles\projectname -> там будет находится ваш .exe файл.

Comment: Не знаете почему в данном методе нет возможности выбрать главный класс? Из совета гугла находил, что надо перестроить проект (reBuild), но это не помогло

Comment: exe то я нашёл, но проблема в том, что он даже на моём компьютере не запускается, не говоря уже о других